# How do I put a [Client] Attribute on methods in a class/bool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to send methods from the client to a server for some movement and I have the following code:

```
public virtual bool GetInput
    {
        get
        {
            if (!active) return false;
            if (inputSystem == null) return false;

            var oldValue = InputValue;

            switch (GetPressed)
            {

                case InputButton.Press:

                    InputValue = type == InputType.Input ? InputSystem.GetButton(input) : Input.GetKey(key);


                    if (oldValue != InputValue)
                    {
                        if (InputValue) OnInputDown.Invoke();
                        else OnInputUp.Invoke();

                        OnInputChanged.Invoke(InputValue);
                    }
                    if (InputValue) OnInputPressed.Invoke();

                    return InputValue;
```

(this is only half the code so as not to make this post super long, but the rest is basically the same stuff and proper endings)

So for other methods, I was able to just put [Client] on top of the methods and boom, everything in the method gets sent from Client to Server successfully and gets executed properly. Problem is I can't do that here and I'm wondering-what can I do to make the invoked methods (OnInputUp, OnInputChanged, etc) get sent and executed on the client?

This entire bool is encompassed in a class if that helps at all (is there a way to just send an entire class and all methods and variables within to a server?). Also the methods are unityevents that are defined elsewhere.

Comment: That is not a method but a field .. Networking doesn't work with fields only methods. Also `[Client]` doesn't send anything to the server or client ... it only makes sure this method can only be executed on a client and will throw an exception on a server. To send calls to the clients you have to use [ClientRpc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientRpcAttribute.html) on all invoked methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I figured out what all the attributes did and then realized [Client] wasn't what I was looking for lol. I've just put [Command] now on everything that all clients need to see as that sends it to the server to be executed.